# Perform An Action when a file is uploaded on windows server 2008 with built-in IIS FTP Server/Service

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

Is there a way to perform some action (start a vbs, batch file, or an exe, etc) upon the successful upload of a file using Windows Server 2008 R2 built-in IIS FTP server/service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, schedule a powershell script to scan the directory every 5 minutes.

Comment: What would such a script look like? Would you run this as a scheduled task or is there a way to have IIS fireoff a powershell when a file is uploaded? I'm not much of a powershell guru, but I've got a fair amount of programming background...

Comment: i feel bad that i can't write the script for you but I would make the script do a simple task:  1. use getChildItem to get a list of files in the FTP location, sorted by newest to oldest 2.  if newer files show up then increment a timestamp value in a cache file and then do your task.   Schedule with windows task manager.  (This could also be done with a old-school batch file as well, depending on what your doing)

Comment: This does not factor the successful completed transfer of files, nor files that are in-flight at the scheduled interval.  With this approach, additional logic is required by the *sending* process to avoid issues (e.g. upload to `~/tmp`, rename to `~/done`)